# What does this mean in PowerPC?

Tags: powerpc

```
stwu      r1, -32(r1) // 32 bytes of space for this function

mflr      r0     

stw       r0, 36(r1)   //stores link register

stw       r30, 24(r1)   // ??

stw       r31, 28(r1)   // Probably makes space for r31?

mr        r31, r1       // r31 = stack pointer
```

This is the beginning of this function, in code above it stores r30 somewhere in the memory, and every function begins this way. But neither r31 nor r30 hold any value in the registers. What sense to store it?

Comment: Maybe stack frame setup. r30 and r31 may be return parameters.

Comment: @Chet r30 and r31 are not return parameters. r31 is typically used as in the example to install the stack frame. I don't know why r31 receives the stack pointer. About r30, it is certainly used as a local variable later in the function. @user3287975 You should look for information related to the `prolog` keyword.

Answer (score 4):

In the PowerPC ELF ABI, registers r14-r31 are defined as non-volatile - they must be preseved across a function call. So, if a function can overwrite the contents of any of these registers, it must save their values in the function prologue, and restore them before returning to the caller.

So, even though your disassembled function hasn't used r30 and r31 yet, it needs to save them on the stack, so it doesn't corrupt the calling-function's nonvolatile state. You'll probably see usage of r30 and r31 later in the function, and the restore (from those same locations on the stack) before the function returns.

I'm assuming that your program conforms to the Power ELF ABI, as that's what defines how your registers are used.

For more information, the Power ELF ABI is at http://openpowerfoundation.org/technical/technical-resources/technical-specifications/ , or https://www.power.org/technology-introduction/standards-specifications/ for the 32-bit versions.